# React api only fetches if data is not being used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I have two state items inside redux store, both of which fetches data from the API.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.postMDBConfig(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=${this.props.apiKey}`);
        this.props.postMoviePopular(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${this.props.apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1&region=US`)
    }
```

But as soon as I pass (or even use in current component) the information down to a child and use the data, it does not fetch.

```
render() {
        return (
            <ItemCarousel MDBConfig={this.props.config} items={this.props.moviesPopular}/>
        );
    }


class ItemCarousel extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const slider = (
            <AwesomeSlider cssModule={AwesomeSliderStyles}>
              <div data-src={`${this.props.config.images.secure_base_url}original${this.props.items[0].poster_path}`}> </div>
            </AwesomeSlider>
          );

        return (
            <div>{slider}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here's what the API fetch looks like when I use vs. don't use the data:

https://ibb.co/G00jzHW (with data not using them)
https://ibb.co/xzkF89R  (no data when using the state variables)

I suspect it has something to do with the rendering lifecycle order, but I have already tried componentWillMount and it still does not work compared to componentDidMount.

Comment: What exactly "does not fetch"?

Comment: The api calls that should be passed into state are not being called thus whenever i USE my this.props.items.image.path_to_img it gets undefined back

Comment: Redux dev tools shows that it gets stuck at @@INIT doesn't do the api calls for some reason

Comment: Does postMDBConfig and postMoviePopular initiate at all?

Comment: it initiates when I am not using data returned in my code, Ive been doing some testing and found that if i console.log out the api data when not using the data, it takes 3 console logs to log them out, maybe that's why i cant use it? but how would i solve that? thanks..

Comment: What does it mean by saying 3 console logs?

Comment: 1st one only inital state inside the logs, 2nd one has the first api call's data, then 3rd one contains the second api call's data. I think it means it takes some time to fetch my data but i am using the data before they are returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can have one state variable such as loading initially true. Once your api calls get resolved then you can update the state variable as false.

Now meanwhile you can add this loading check on your  component. It will help you out to render the component using the API data.

```
render() {
    const itemCarousel = (this.state.loading) ? '' : <ItemCarousel MDBConfig= 
             {this.props.config} items={this.props.moviesPopular}/>
    return ( 
        {itemCarousel}
    )
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to return an object for some reason but you've pushed me in the right direction. Thanks a lot, will upvote when I reach 15 reputation.